Elliptic regularity for Dirac Witten
Witten Operator fans,
I have a question about the proof of that the Dirac Witten operator is a Fredholm operator. In the book of geometric relativity by Dan A. Lee when he is proving the isomorphism between $H^1_{-q}$ and $L^2_{-q-1}$ he state that the Dirac-Witten operator is a Fredholm operator of index 0.
I have been trying to show this statement for a while and here is my attempt. Can someone please correct it. First I show an "Elliptic regularity" proposition and then I use it to show that it is a Fredholm operator with positive index to conclude that it is injective just using the same proof as Dan A. Lee.
[Elliptic regularity for Dirac Witten operator]
Let $(M,g,k)$ be a spin initial data set satisfying the dominant energy condition. Then for all $u\in H^1_{-q}(M)$,
\begin{equation}
    ||u||_{H^1_{-q}}\leq C\cdot \big( || \tilde{D}(u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}} + ||u||_{L^2_{-q}} \big),
\end{equation}
Let $u\in L^2_{-q-1}(M)$ be such that,
$$(u,\tilde{D}(v))_{L^2_{-q-1}}=0 \quad v\in C^\infty_c(M).$$
Then $u\in H^1_{-q}$ and $\tilde{D}(u)=0$.
[Begin of the proof]
From the Schrödinger-Lichnerowicz formula for the Dirac-Witten operator,
\begin{equation}
    \tilde{D}^2 \psi= \tilde{\nabla}^*\tilde{\nabla}\psi + \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \mu + Je_0\bigg)\psi.
\end{equation}
We have that,
\begin{equation*}
    ||\tilde{D}(u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}} = ||\tilde{\nabla} u||_{{L^2_{-q-1}}} + (u, \frac{1}{2}(\mu + Je_0)u)_{L^2_{-q-1}}
\end{equation*}
Since we have the dominant energy condition we can affirm that,
\begin{equation*}
    ||\tilde{D}(u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}} \geq ||\nabla u||_{L^2_{-q-1}}.
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation*}
    ||u||_{H^1_{-q}} = ||u||_{L^2_{-q}}+||\nabla u||_{L^2_{-q-1}}\leq C( ||u||_{L^2_{-q}}+||\tilde{D}(u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}}).
\end{equation*}
From the initial condition in the second statement by definition we obtain that $u\in dom(\tilde{D}^*)=dom(\tilde{D})$ and $\tilde{D}(u)=0=\tilde{D}^*(u)$
Now to show the second statement we just need to proof that $||u||_{H^1_{-q}}<\infty$. First,
we are going to take a family of compactly supported functions $\{\phi_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subset C^\infty_c(M)$ such that
for every compact set $K\subset M^n$ we have that there exists a subsequence in this family such that for all $n\geq N$ and $\phi_n\bigg|_K = 1$. Then using
that $L^2_{-q-1}\hookrightarrow L^2_{-q+\epsilon}$ then,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        || u||_{H^1_{-q}}\leq& \limsup_{n\to \infty} ||\phi_n u||_{H^1_{-q}}\\
                         \leq&   \limsup_{n\to \infty} C\cdot \big( || \tilde{D}(\phi_n u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}} + ||\phi_n u||_{L^2_{-q}} \big) \\
                            =&   \limsup_{n\to \infty} C\cdot \big( || \tilde{D}(\phi_n)u||_{L^2_{-q-1}} +||\phi_n \tilde{D}( u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}}  + ||\phi_n u||_{L^2_{-q}} \big) \\
                        \leq&  \limsup_{n\to \infty} C\cdot \big( || \tilde{D}(\phi_n)||_{L^2_{-q-1}}|| u||_{L^2_{-q-1}} + ||\phi_n||_{L^2_{-q}} || u||_{L^2_{-q}} \big) \\
                        \leq& C\cdot 2 \cdot ||u||_{L^2}.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Since, $u\in L^2_{-q-1}$ we can conclude that $u\in H^1_{-q}$. $\textbf{QED}$
[Dirac-Witten operator is Fredholm]     Let $(M,g,k)$ be a spin initial data set satisfying the dominant energy condition. Then the Dirac-Witten operator is a Fredholm operator with positive intex.
[Begin of the proof]
We are going to show point by point each of the properties of the Fredholm operator,
The Dirac-Witten operator is bounded and linear, the operator is linear by definition. Since, $||\tilde{D}(u)||_{L^2_{-q-1}}\leq n||\tilde{\nabla}u ||_{L^2_{-q-1}}\leq n||u||_{H^1_{-q}}$ the it is bounded.
The dimension of the kernel is finite, to show this thing we are going to show that the unit ball in the kernel is compact and then this subspace will be finite dimensional.
We will take $\{u_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subset Ker(\tilde{D})$ such that $||u_i||_{H^1_{-q}}\leq 1$ then we have by the compact embedding that this sequence admits a convergent subsequence in $L^2_{-q}$.
By the previous proposition we have that the subsequence will be monotone therefore Cauchy in $H^1_{-q}$. We have shown that every bounded sequence in the ball admits a convergent subsequence then the ball it is compact in the kernel and we can conclude that the kernel is finite dimensional by Riesz.
The range of $\tilde{D}$ is closed, since we have that the kernel it is finite dimensional then the range it admits a closed complement.
The dimension of the cokernel is finite, by the elliptic regularity we have that the $ker(\tilde{D}^*)\subset ker(\tilde{D})$ since $dim(ker(\tilde{D}^*))= dim( coker(\tilde{D}))$ we conclude that $dim( coker(\tilde{D}))<\infty$. $\textbf{QED}$
Thanks in advance.
